# Laravel Logging - custom channel not writing

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm running Laravel 5.6 and I'm trying to log into custom files (other than app/storage/logs/laravel.log). I would like to create a log in this specific location:

```
app/storage/logs/auth/register.log
```

I added this to config/logging.php:

```
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
'channels' => [
       'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single', 'auth'],
       ],
      'auth' => [
        'driver' => 'auth',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/auth/register.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 30,
       ],

       ...
```

And the default channel specified in .env is:

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

Then I call logging like this:

```
use Log;
Log::channel('auth')->debug('Some message');
```

But nothing happens. I tried creating the file manually before logging to it, it also did not work. I already run `chmod 777 -R storage/` but it didnt help. I want to be able to write to different channels at the same time. Anyone knows what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: `'driver' => 'auth'` no log driver called `auth` unless you implemented it, use `single` or `daily` driver instead.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as **Ben** mentioned in the comments, the problem was this line:

```
'driver' => 'auth',
```

From Laravel's config/logging.php:

```
| Available Drivers: "single", "daily", "slack", "syslog",
|                    "errorlog", "custom", "stack"
```

Changing 'auth' to 'single' fixed the problem.